# Why has my object detached itself from the parent?

Tags: unity, animation, blender, models, objects

I made an two objects in blender, animated them, and saved them.

Firstly, when I reloaded them, half of the animations I created had disappeared, which is annoying itself but the real annoyance is that the item, a sword, detached itself from the parent, the character. I exported as fbx but for some reason it is completely seperated.

Also, my mesh has holes everywhere. Is this normal for untextured objects?

> How it should look 
>   [image: How it should look]
>
> Whats actually happening
>   [image: Whats actually happening]

Comment: To clarify, in blender the lighting makes it look like it has holes in depending on the angle, but it is covered in faces. In unity there are literally holes in it

Comment: For the holes, did you make sure that the face normals were pointing outside of your model? For the detached sword, 

Comment: What file format did you use to export to Unity? [The recommended format is .fbx](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/3D-formats.html). While Unity appears to be able to work directly with .blend files at first glance, there are a lot of issues with that.

Comment: Yes I used .fbx. How would I check the normals? The sword seems to be fine actually but its location is off. The man however I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

Your normals are flipped, [search for shortcut or how to flip normals in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12165/how-to-make-all-faces-flip-to-the-right-consistent-direction), that is causing invisible faces. Make sure your sword is parented correctly to the bone that is holding the sword.

I would suggest setting up position for a sword in [T pose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-pose) and to not animate the sword position itself `(this could have been the problem, as object was animated, once not in Blender world space it MIGHT behave differently relative to other objects)`, it should be driven by position and rotation of the bones.

The common practice is to separate sword and character models, then parent a sword to a `GameObject` that would be a bone that should hold a sword.

This is from my old project as an example.
[image: Sword In 3D Model Hand]